# Modify matplotlib y values after plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, kde-plasma

I am using matplotlib to plot a KDE. The issue with this is I'm using `ax.imshow`, which only takes in a grid and an extent. Meaning it will linearly space the data from the grid using the minimum value in the extent to the maximum.

I need to flip the y axes (doable), but then I also need to arbitrarily scale every y point by a function, not just a simple factor. As an example, if the y value is `5`, I need it to be mapped to `f(5)=13` and `6` should be mapped to `f(6)=22`. The point is, it's not a simple scale.

Is there any way of modifying these y values after they have been plotted, or am I forced to modify these values before-hand.

Comment: It would help if you were to provide code ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that shows where you are stuck and the function that you want to use to scale the y axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to modify the y values, but I could find a way to modify the labels of the yaxis.

By scaling the yaxes with the desired function and its inverse, using the following:

`ax.set_yscale('function', **{'functions':[forward, inverse]})`

Then scaling the axes ytick values by the desired function and setting the ytick *labels* to be the scaled yticks, you effectively scale the y values:

`ax.set_yticklabels(forward(ax.get_yticks()))`

Comment: Omg, you still need to provide minimum code for other to understand, although you got a solution. This will help others with similar issues:)